# How do I return an index.html file from express using the package 'express-https-redirect'

Tags: node.js, express, https

I have the following code which is defaulting to use HTTPS, I'm just unclear how to send an index.html file back

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs'),
app = express(),
staticRoot = __dirname + '/',
httpsRedirect = require('express-https-redirect');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));

app.use('/', httpsRedirect())

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the **html** **file** usually asfollows

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Note: **express-https-redirect**  middleware redirects non-secure access to HTTPS Only.